# Duplicate request sent in official tutorial example

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm following the official tutorial (https://nextjs.org/learn) on next.js. I'm using Next.js 14.0.2, node v18.19.0, npm 10.2.3. I also downloaded and tried the final example from Github(https://github.com/vercel/next-learn/tree/main/dashboard/final-example).
What I did is following:

1. add `reactStrictMode: false` in `next.config.js` to make sure React
   strict mode is off.
2. comment out the log statement `console.log('Fetching revenue data...');` and `console.log('Data fetch completed after 3 seconds.');`
   in the `data.ts` file, `fetchRevenue` method.
3. add the log `console.log('rendering revenue-chart');` in
   `revenue-chart.tsx`, `console.log('render dashboard main page');` in
   `@/app/dashboard/(overview)/page.tsx`.
4. run the program and navigate to http://localhost:3000/dashboard.

In the console, you will see

```
render dashboard main page
rendering revenue-chart
Fetching revenue data...
Data fetch completed after 3 seconds.
render dashboard main page
rendering revenue-chart
Fetching revenue data...
Data fetch completed after 3 seconds.
```

which means the page rendered twice and DB is fetched twice. What's happening here?

This looks like a trivial question related to the specific tutorial example. However I feel this relates to how next.js renders under the hood. Can you explain the mechanism next.js used? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to avoid duplicate data fetching, you can conditionally execute the data fetching logic only on the server side.

Comment: Hi @ADITYA, the data fetching logic is already happening on the server side, as the components are server components.